# Tropical self intersection number of boundary divisor on toroidal embedding

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, tropical-geometry

Let $X_0 \subset X$ a toroidal embedding without self intersections and denote by $\overline{\Sigma}$ its corresponding (weakly embedded) extended conical simplicial complex. Let $D$ be a divisor on $X$ supported away from $X_0$. Then $D$ corresponds to a continuous integral function on \begin{eqnarray*}
\psi \colon |\Sigma| \to \mathbb{R}
\end{eqnarray*}
which restricted to each cone $\sigma \in \Sigma$ is linear. I want to compute the self intersection number 
\begin{eqnarray*}
D^n \in A_0(X) \simeq \mathbb{Z}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $n = \dim(X)$.

I would like to do this using tropical intersection theory on weakly embedded extended cone complexes http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04604. For this, I have to find a divisor 
\begin{eqnarray*}F \sim D
\end{eqnarray*}
linearly equivalent to $D$ which intersects the open set $X_0$ non trivially and has transversal intersections with all boundary strata.

How can I do this?

Is there another way to compute this intersection number combinatorially on the cone complex?